# FramelessWindowHint in QGraphicsWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a subclassed QGraphicsWidget and in the constructor I can make it into a dialog window, like so

```
myClass::myClass(QGraphicsScene *myScene,
                   QGraphicsWidget *parent) : QGraphicsWidget(parent, Qt::Window)
{

}
```

This will give me a full Qt Dialog window that I can resize with a blue top bar, a Qt Icon, and a close button.

I want a frameless window though. Whenever I initialize with

```
myClass::myClass(QGraphicsScene *myScene,
                   QGraphicsWidget *parent) : QGraphicsWidget(parent, Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
{

}
```

or do

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

or

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
```

I found this technique in the basicgraphicslayout.pro in the Qt Creator examples.

The window disappears and my QGraphicsWidget continues on as normal as if I never passed the Qt::Window flag.

My question is how do I make a frameless window in a QGraphicsScene? How do I edit the Dialog window attributes when it is inside a QGraphicsScene/Widget?

Thanks.

Comment: read [ask], review the [tour] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Does the frameless window really need to be inside the QGraphicsScene?  If you only need a window to float over the top, you could just have your widget inherit from QWidget instead, and maybe set the WindowStaysOnTopHint|FramelessWindowHint flags for good measure.